# Russian: How to learn which cases / prepositions to use with each verb

Tags: russian

I am learning Russian and am between B1 - B2 level and still having some difficulty finding a good strategy for learning which preposition and case to use with each verb. Does anyone have any good resources or hints on how to go about this?  I use Anki heavily so tend towards solutions I can put into flashcard. Does anyone know of any good Anki decks that may help (or at least draw some inspiration from).

Answer (score 1):

As a native, I recommend reading [this article](https://www.thoughtco.com/prepositional-case-in-russian-4773323) on the prepositional case to better understand interlingual concepts. It explains how to consider the use of prepositions before using them with a verb. While you will gain understanding about how things work, practice is still necessary.